# Convert uint8_t array to structure in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I'm beginner and I have a problem. I have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
  char data[26];
  int index;
  Placa_baza pb; // char nume_placa[10], int index_placa;
} PC;
```

And a structure vector:

```
static PC computers[5] = { ... };
```

I need to have a vector of type `uint8_t pc[5*sizeof(computers)]` instead of the structure vector.
Is it well declared that way? :

```
uint8_t pc[5*sizeof(computers)]
```

How can I convert (cast) vector `uint8_t pc[5*sizeof(computers)]` to `PC`?

To use the `uint8_t` pointer to address the structure, how should it be written?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please describe what you want to achieve by doing what you are asking about. I have a feeling that it can and should be done differently. You might also want to read [ask] and provide a [mre], right after you took the [tour].

Comment: I think you can have an equivalent memory w.r.t `struct PC` for a `uint8_t` array but how will you extract different members portably is a problem

Comment: I have a homework for a school project as a struct vector to be a vector of type uint8_t. And cast the new vector to PC. That it's all.

Comment: `computers` is already an array of 5, do you really want `pc[5*sizeof(computers)]`,probably you want `pc[5*sizeof(computers[0])]` or `pc[sizeof(computers)]`

Comment: @IrAM I understand, thank you. But I want to replace the array structure with uint8_t array , so the structue array disappears.

Comment: It is important to know **why** the structure is supposed to be available as a `uint8_t` array. If it is just so the structure can be written to or read from a file or network connection, then merely accessing the bytes of the structure itself with a pointer converted to `uint8_t` may suffice. If the reason is something else, a different solution may be required. Explain the problem further, with context.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Very good observation. In the first phase, I worked only as a problem to learn to work with structures. I talked to my teacher, and he told me that it must be a vector of type uint8_t because the data received from the network is not always of the type of my structure and I have to convert it to the type of structures

Comment: There are multiple ways in which data for a structure might be sent over a network. Another system with the exact same layout of the structure and representations of its members might send the bytes that represent the structure in memory. In that case, you would recreate the structure on your system by putting exactly those bytes into the memory of your structure. An easy way to do this is to use `memcpy` to copy the bytes from the network buffer into your structure. (Sometimes the structure itself can be used directly as the buffer, but only when it is known the next bytes read are for it.)

Comment: Another possibility is that the network data contains values in various fields, which are likely somewhat different from how the members of your structure are represented. In that case, you have to copy the values from the network data and insert them individually into members of the structure. The ways to do this depend on the specifics of the network data and the structures. To get further information, you must provide more details about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pc` array, which could serve as a backup for the `PC` data is too large: it is sufficient to define it as:

```
uint8_t pc[sizeof(computers)];
```

Or possibly:

```
uint8_t pc[5 * sizeof(PC)];
```

You can then copy `computers` to `pc` with:

```
memcpy(pc, computers, sizeof pc);
```

You could also use a pointer to access the `pc` array as an array of `PC`:

```
PC *p = (PC *)pc;  // Don't do this!
```

Note however that this has undefined behavior as the byte array `pc` might not be properly aligned to access members of the `PC` structure, especially the `index` member and using such a pointer is a violation of the strict aliasing rule. It would be much better to define `pc` as `PC pc[5];` and access this array via a `uint8_t` pointer of so required.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and for the previous editing. All the best. If problems occur, I come back with edit :)

Comment: It's also a strict aliasing violation to access objects via `p`

Comment: @chqrlie: The rule is any effective type can be accessed by a character type. There is no rule that an effective character type can be accessed by any type, even if the alignment is correct. The advice given in this answer is dangerous; it will break in some compilers.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: Below program is just demonstration purpose, it may not behave same way with all compilers/systems. You can use it to test your compilers or systems behavior and modify accordingly.**

In the below program am copying the contents from the structure `computers` to `unit8_t`.

as you can see its not easy and not portable, because we need to extract the data as per the boundaries of memory, allocated for variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char nume_placa[10];
    int index_placa;
}Placa_baza;

typedef struct {
    char data[26];
    int index;
    Placa_baza pb;
}PC;

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(int) = %zu\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(Placa_baza) = %zu\n", sizeof(Placa_baza));
    printf("sizeof(PC) = %zu\n", sizeof(PC));
    
    static PC computers[3] = { {"data1",1,"comp1", 0}, {"data2",2,"comp2", 1}, {"data3",3,"comp3", 2} };
    
    printf("sizeof(computers) = %zu\n\n", sizeof(computers));
    
    for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
        printf("data = %s, index =%d, pb.nume_placa =%s, pb.index_placa =%d\n",
            computers[i].data,
            computers[i].index,
            computers[i].pb.nume_placa, 
            computers[i].pb.index_placa
        );
        
    uint8_t uint8_t_pc[sizeof(computers)] = {0};
    
// for copying the contents from pc (uint8_t), used same variable names as that of structures

/*  typedef struct { */

    char data[26];
    int index;
    
/*      Placa_baza pb;
    } PC; */

/* typedef struct
{ */

    char nume_placa[10];
    int index_placa;
        
/*    }Placa_baza;
*/

    printf("\n sizeof(uint8_t_pc) = %zu\n", sizeof(uint8_t_pc));
    
    memcpy(uint8_t_pc,computers,sizeof(computers));
    
    int count = 0;
    uint8_t* temp = uint8_t_pc;
    
    printf("\n **From uint8_t memory ***\n");
    
    while(count < 3) {
    
        memcpy(data, temp, 26);
        // since there is a padding of 2 bytes , so extract from 28
        memcpy(&index, temp+28, 4);
        
        memcpy(nume_placa, temp+32, 10);
        //again there is a padding of 2 bytes
        memcpy(&index_placa, temp+44, 4);
        
        printf("data = %s, index = %d, nume_placa =%s , index_placa =%d\n", data, index, nume_placa, index_placa);
        temp = temp+sizeof(computers[0]);
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(int) = 4                                                                                                                                  
sizeof(Placa_baza) = 16                                                                                                                          
sizeof(PC) = 48                                                                                                                                  
sizeof(computers) = 144                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                 
data = data1, index =1, pb.nume_placa =comp1, pb.index_placa =0                                                                                  
data = data2, index =2, pb.nume_placa =comp2, pb.index_placa =1                                                                                  
data = data3, index =3, pb.nume_placa =comp3, pb.index_placa =2                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                 
 sizeof(uint8_t_pc) = 144                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                 
 **From uint8_t memory ***                                                                                                                       
data = data1, index = 1, nume_placa =comp1 , index_placa =0                                                                                      
data = data2, index = 2, nume_placa =comp2 , index_placa =1                                                                                      
data = data3, index = 3, nume_placa =comp3 , index_placa =2
```

[online source](https://onlinegdb.com/Ci2rlxquF)

**Update:**
Indeed we can use [`offsetof`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html) to get the offset of any member of the structure, so the statements inside `while` can also be replaced by below statments.

```
memcpy(data, temp+offsetof(PC, data), sizeof(computers[count].data));
memcpy(&index, temp+offsetof(PC, index), sizeof index);
memcpy(nume_placa, temp+offsetof(PC, pb.nume_placa), sizeof computers[count].pb.nume_placa);
memcpy(&index_placa, temp+offsetof(PC, pb.index_placa), sizeof index_placa);
```

Comment: I did the same solution like you, but I dont want to use static PC computers[3]. I want 
and use uint_8 array, and i  don't know how to code..

Comment: `static PC computers[3]` is used for storing the data, if you are getting data in some other way , you can directly copy to `uint8_t*` buffer (either array or malloced pointer)

Comment: :) Glad it helped, but careful as warned already its not a universal solution.

Comment: `memcpy(&index, temp+28, 4);` is better as `memcpy(&index, temp+offsetof(PC, index), sizeof index);`. `offsetof` is defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, i really thought of adding it , but that also looks compiler specific, so just gave without it.

Comment: It is not compiler specific; it is more portable, since it replaces hard-coded compiler-specific values with strictly conforming expressions defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you are right, it is not bad as I thought.updated my answer for completeness.